# Solving maze using recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking, maze

I am to solve maze using recursion in java but when I try to run I get a Stack overflow error. A maze starts at a + and the path that leads to the end is also +, ends at a -, walls are X, spaces are potential paths, '.' will mark a dead end path. What I think causes the error is the backtracking step. The code shown is the part that I get the error on. When The maze path is a straight line the maze works fine. Any help is much appreciated.

```
/*Sample maze that causes errors
       XXXXXXXXXXXX
       +   XXX    -
       XXX XXX XXXX
       XXX  XX XXXX
       XX         X
       XXXXXXXXXXXX
*/

   public  boolean isValidSpot(int r, int c) { // r and c represent position in 2d array
       if(r < nrow && c < ncol)  //make sure current postion is not out of bounds
       {  
        return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

   public  boolean traverse(char[][] maze, int r, int c) {
       if(isValidSpot(r, c)) {
           if(maze[r][c]=='X')
               return false;
           if(maze[r][c]=='-') {
               return true;}

           maze[r][c]='+';

           //right
           if(traverse(maze, r, c+1))
               return true;
           //up
           if(traverse(maze, r-1, c ))//error on this line
               return true;

           //down
           if(traverse(maze, r+1, c))//error on this line
               return true;


           //left
           if(traverse(maze, r, c - 1))
               return true;

           //backtrack
           maze[r][c]='.';
           return false;

       }

       return false;
   }
```

The solved maze look something like this

```
/*
        XXXXXXXXXXXX
        ++++XXX++++-
        XXX+XXX+XXXX
        XXX+ XX+XXXX
        XX.+++++...X
        XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: If you output the maze with the already found path at each step, what does it tell you?

Comment: r-1 and c-1 should be greather than or equal to 0 add the condition

Answer (score 0):

Code to traverse through the **maze** is below remember **'+'** represents that it's the start and **'*'** represent that we have traversed it so we don't traverse it again other wise it will lead to **stackoverflow** since traverse method will keep on calling it self until overflow happens.

from each cell we are traversing **up**, **down** , **left** and **right** if there is path we will reach to out **goal**.

### Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Maze{
    //checks weather the spot is valid
    public  static boolean isValidSpot(int r, int c, int nrow, int ncol) {
        return r < nrow && c < ncol && r >= 0 && c >= 0; 
    }
    //traverses through the maze
    public static boolean traverse(final char[][] maze, final int r, final int c) {

        int nrow = maze.length, ncol = maze[0].length;

        if(isValidSpot(r, c, nrow, ncol)) {
            if(maze[r][c] == 'X' || maze[r][c] == '.' || maze[r][c] == '*')
                return false;
            if(maze[r][c]=='-') {
                return true;
            }

            maze[r][c]='*';

            //right
            if(traverse(maze, r, c+1))
                return true;
            //up
            if(traverse(maze, r-1, c ))
                return true;

            //down
            if(traverse(maze, r+1, c))
                return true;

            //left
            if(traverse(maze, r, c - 1))
                return true;

            //backtrack
            maze[r][c]='.';
            return false;

        }

        return false;
    }
    ///////////////Main////////////////
    public static void main(String ...$){
        var out = System.out;

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        list.add("+   XXX    -");
        list.add("XXX XXX XXXX");
        list.add("XXX  XX XXXX");
        list.add("XX         X");
        list.add("XXXXXXXXXXXX");

        char[][] maze =new char[list.size()][];
        //converting list of string to a 2D char array
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            String str = list.get(i);
            maze[i] = str.toCharArray(); 
        }
        boolean pathExists = false;
        for(int i =0;i<maze.length;i++)
            for(int j =0;j<maze[i].length;j++)
                if(maze[i][j] == '+'){
                    //out.println("found");
                    pathExists = traverse(maze,i,j);
                }
        out.println(pathExists);
        for(int i =0;i<maze.length;i++){
            for(int j =0;j<maze[i].length;j++)
                out.print(maze[i][j]);
            out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

### output:

```
$ javac Maze.java && java Maze 
true
XXXXXXXXXXXX
****XXX****-
XXX*XXX*XXXX
XXX**XX*XXXX
XX  ****...X
XXXXXXXXXXXX
```